# echo/print specific element

Tags: php, ajax

i tried this example on ajax [here](http://www.tutorials2learn.com/2010/03/scripts/submit-html-form-ajax/)

and i wonder if i can echo/print a specific element of the array at the php side
let's say i just want to print the second element which is "lastName"
i tried `echo $t2lpostData[1]`
it gives me error
 "Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\thank-you.php on line 12"

help plz,,

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $t2lpostData["lastName"]
```

You have to access it by name instead of index.

Comment: i did as you told me , but it's still gives me the same error
"Undefined index: lastName "... -__-